# simple ways to create rdf/xml using php?

Tags: php, xml, rdf

what's the best/simplest/easiest way to create rdf/xml with php?

ideally i would like to use simpleXML - but i believe it doesn't support namespaces?

failing that maybe simpleDOM? id rather not use DOM since it tends to confuse me a lot!

perhaps there is some other way?

thanks for your help!

:)

nb: i tried to post an example but couldn't get it to format properly (no line breaks with backticks, only one line at a time usng the GUI) so any help with that would be good to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using [ARC](http://arc.semsol.org/). It provides with a collection of parsers and serializers that allow the conversion of triples from/to multiple formats.

Answer (score 2):

I think all answers above are outdated. Meanwhile **[EasyRdf](http://www.easyrdf.org)** seems to be the hippest child in town. It has properties which fully match the zeitgeist such as:

- Intuitive interface
- Hosted on Github, many "likes"
- Good documentation
- Test backed

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [RDF API for PHP](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/rdfapi/index.html). **RAP** is a software package for parsing, querying, manipulating, serializing and serving RDF models.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I looked at RDF, [Redland](http://librdf.org/) was the tool of choice. It has [a PHP interface](http://librdf.org/docs/php.html), I suggest looking at that.